# Nativescript - picking an image from gallery and sending it as an attachment

Tags: nativescript

I'm using nativescript-imagepicker to pick an image from the gallery and then send that file as an attachment using nativescript-email.

For some reason I didn't get the permissions dialog (Android) - no matter.

After an image is picked, I get something like this in

```
content://com.android.providers.media.documents/document/image%3A742
```

What I'd like to do is take this uri and pass to nativescript-email and use it as an attachment. The problem seems to be that the email plug-in doesn't seem to understand that format and also that path doesn't seem to be a physical path.

So I have to copy the image to my folder and then send it from there. That seems like a waste of storage and time.

1. Any way to convert that content uri into a physical path that can be used by the email plug-in.
2. Barring that, I can copy the file via imageSource.getImage(). Can I set the file dimensions? Looks like I can set the quality. No documentation on that. I assume that sets the quality and not the dimensions.

Thanks.

Comment: You can pass options  `getImage({ maxWidth: 200, maxHeight: 100 })` based on the source code https://github.com/NativeScript/nativescript-imagepicker/blob/master/nativescript-imagepicker/viewmodel.android.ts#L36-L44

Comment: Thanks that helps. Looks like the requested size is not completely respected but close enough.